# Is it "OK" to install Ubuntu on one laptop and put the SSD into another?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, hardware

If I install Ubuntu on say.. my intel based netbook (atom) and then take out the ssd and stick in into another intel based laptop (i3) for use would there be any issues that would arise? drivers, packages not installed, idk? I do know in windows this would be a major no no.

Answer (score 12):

You can, I have done it myself without any issues.

Though as the comment says, you need to remove the 3rd party drivers before moving the SSD to the other.

Comment: 1 cave-at: remove 3rd party drivers. Especially when the 2 systems have different video cards (intel/nvidia/amd).

Comment: I added that to my answer. Thank for posting this comment.

Comment: experimented (12.10) and it's ok if no propriety software installed (kernal will detect new hardware and installed the driver appropritely)... and also done it with Windows 7 HDD to other pc also with no driver installed, ok with all needed driver will be downloaded and installed later. Tested.

Answer (score 4):

I've done it myself as well, it is completely possible however there could be a few settings off (i.e. Screen resolution). If the new hardware/laptop requires new third party drivers Ubuntu will automatically call that our for you or you can just manually installed them to get better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it works extremely well. One thing I came across doing this, was that my network card was not auto detected anymore.

I found out that a custom rule targeting my specific network card had been added to /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules by the ubuntu installer to make sure eth0 would always be eth0 even if another card was added. I deleted the file and on next boot everything was well. I don't remember the Ubuntu version, so YMMV. But in case you run into trouble, /etc/udev/rules.d/ might be the place to look.